# Process.WaitForExit() is not working with multiple excel and word file

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Process.WaitForExit() is not working if i open multiple excel sheets, the program simply runs but if i open only one excel then it will hit the Process.WaitForExit(); line.

sample code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.FileName = "D:\\test.xlsx";
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
                    try
                    {
                        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                        {
                            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                            if (saveasUserReport)
                            {
                                DateTime reportUpdatedDateTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(outputPath);
                                if (reportUpdatedDateTime > reportCreationDateTime)
                                {
                                    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(NotificationHelper.GetDisplayText(BrandingTypes.Message, "Do you want to save?"),
                                        NotificationHelper.GetDisplayText(BrandingTypes.Message, "Reports"), MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                                    if (dialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) 
                                        saveReport = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
```

Comment: Post some code. Excel won't create new process by default, so process will exit only when you close all the excel files

Comment: You should post some relevant code.

Comment: How do we handle if Excel won't create new process, is there any way i can track whether user want to save the excel or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to capture any changes in file. once user makes any changes in excel and save it, it will fire an event.

```
private System.IO.FileSystemWatcher fsw;
fsw = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                             | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```